# Creating time series in R with given time-stamps and values

Tags: r, time-series

I create the following time series

```
t = seq(as.POSIXct('2014-12-05 10:01:00'), length.out = 4, by = 'mins')
x = c(1,3,4,2)
y = as.ts(x,t)
```

When I try to view (in a plot) my time series, the time tags are not the values I entered in *t*.

```
plot(y)
time(y)
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: one way is to use the `xts` class instead: `library(xts);
y <- xts(x,t)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `xts` package, ie. create the Time-Series as an `xts` object instead and then leverage on `plot.xts`:

```
library(xts)
y.xts <- xts(x, t)
plot(y.xts)
```

[image]